# Access denied to mysql service from grails service on docker container

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, grails

Access is denied to mysql service(running on a private AWS instance) from docker container (running on another private AWS instance). Both instances are running in same VPC, in same (private) subnet. I have deployed a grails app inside the docker container which attempts to connect to the mysql db instance.

I am building the grails app locally before building and pushing the docker image on a docker host.

Production section of application.yml file for application on my local machine: 
(Note: Here, config shows root/root as username and password. I have configured a user 'blah' with password 'blah' with all privileges on mydb with exactly the same result.)

```
production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.54:3306/mydb?useSSL=false
            driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
            username: root
            password: root
```

Docker container is deployed on AWS instance as

```
        docker run --restart always --name grails-gumball-v1 -td -p 8080:8080 krutikavk/grails-gumball:v1.0
```

From mysql logs at /var/log/mysqld.log:

```
200313 12:02:43  1987 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1987 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1988 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1988 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1989 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1989 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1990 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1990 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1991 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1991 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1992 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1992 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1993 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1993 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1994 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1994 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1995 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1995 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
         1996 Connect   root@ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal on mydb
         1996 Connect   Access denied for user 'root'@'ip-10-0-0-232.us-west-2.compute.internal' (using password: YES)
```

I also have port 3306 open on AWS mysql instance to receive incoming connections.

What am I missing here in configuration/application.yml/otherwise to get mySQL to accept remote connections?

Comment: In mysql shell did you grant correctly root user or the user you want to use with enough privileges for remote connections? For example with command: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`